# Converting a string from an interger isn't working, whats going wrong?

Tags: c++

I can't seem to figure out whats causing the issue. I want the program to read the list of numbers from the file, print out the list, then total up all the numbers, but when I try to find the total, I cannot convert the string values into integer values

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int total = 0;
    string line;
    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("random.txt");
    while (getline(myfile, line)) {
        cout << line << endl;
        total = total + static_cast<int>(line);
    }
    cout << total;
}
```

Comment: There's already several answered questions about converting a string to an int in C++ on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @paper1111 your "possible duplicate" is in the wrong direction... this question needs string to int.

Comment: Your question is not 100% clear - can there be more than one number per line?  If not, Gary's answer's on the money.  If so, you may want to use `int number; while (myfile >> number) { cout << number << '\n'; total += number; }`.

Comment: @TonyD oh sorry I was confused

Answer (score 1):

You probably want

```
total = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); ++i) {
  total = total + static_cast<int>(line[i]);
}
```

Edit: 
I misunderstood the question. The following code should work.
The input file is

11 22

10

and the result is 43.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <sstream>
 using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int total = 0;
    string line;
    ifstream myfile;
    int line_int = 0;
    myfile.open("random.txt");

    while (getline(myfile, line)) {
      cout << line << endl;
      istringstream iss(line);
      while(iss >> line_int)
        total = total + line_int;
    }
    cout << total;
}
```

Comment: `static_cast<int>(line[i])` adds the ASCII codes for the characters in each line - probably not what's wanted.

Comment: Thanks. I misunderstood the question. Another way to convert string to int is using string stream. I have implemented the method in my edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `C++ 11` try [`stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol):

```
total = total + stoi(line);
```